# Is it wrong to pass BuildContext to bloc in order to be able to read parameters from there?

Tags: flutter, dart, parameters, bloc

I have this line of code to read parameters from the context inside my bloc:

```
final existingNote = event.context.getArgument<Note>();
```

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58505881/4943676) that it's bad to pass BuildContext to bloc, so at this point, I should read the parameter outside and pass it to bloc; but reading parameters isn't considered business logic since I'm handling the data? At this point I think the answer is no but I'd like to see if anyone can give me an explanation on why it isn't or, if it is, on what options we have to handle parameters.

Comment: `but reading parameters isn't considered business logic since I'm handling the data?`  I wouldn't call reading parameters logic.  And if it was, it would be e.g. UI logic, not business logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing the `BuildContext` to a BLoC in Flutter is generally not a good practice for the following reasons:

1. **Separation of UI and Logic:** In Flutter, it's important to maintain a clear separation between the user interface (UI) and business logic. A BLoC should not depend on a `BuildContext` because it can tightly couple the business logic to the UI, which hinders reusability and testability.
2. **Testability:** If you want to write unit tests for your BLoC, it becomes challenging when the BLoC relies on the `BuildContext`. The `BuildContext` is a Flutter-specific class that is difficult to create and simulate, especially in testing scenarios.
3. **Clear Responsibilities:** A BLoC should focus on data processing and business logic, not on interacting with the user interface. Passing `BuildContext` to a BLoC results in unclear and mixed responsibilities.

To address this issue, reduce dependencies between the UI and your BLoC. In Flutter, you can achieve this by using mechanisms like `Stream` or `StreamController` to transmit data between your UI and BLoC. Your BLoC can send data to the UI without requiring the `BuildContext`.

Instead, use the `BuildContext` in widgets to handle UI-specific tasks such as navigation or displaying Snackbars. When your BLoC modifies data or triggers actions, the UI can respond without the BLoC needing to know about the `BuildContext`.

This approach promotes a cleaner separation of responsibilities and makes your code more testable and maintainable.