# Having issues with register page with Bloc in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, supabase

I'm following a guide on how to integrate Supabase with a OTP registration page. Around 9:51 in this [vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7ysVtZ5Row), they access their build context, however because I'm trying have this handled with a bloc, I'm curious how to handle it

```
class RegisterBloc extends Bloc<RegisterEvent, RegisterState> {
  RegisterBloc() : super(RegisterInitial());

  final emailController = TextEditingController();

  bool isButtonEnabled = false;

  @override
  Stream<RegisterState> mapEventToState(
   RegisterEvent event,
  ) async* {
if (event is OnTextChangedEvent) {
  if (isButtonEnabled != checkIfSignUpButtonEnabled()) {
    isButtonEnabled = checkIfSignUpButtonEnabled();
    yield RegisterButtonEnableChangedState(isEnabled: isButtonEnabled);
  }
} else if (event is RegisterTappedEvent) {
  if (checkValidatorsOfTextField()) {
    try {
      yield LoadingState();
      AuthService.register(emailController.text);
      // if (mounted) {
      // TODO fix this line below accessing context
      // ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      //     const SnackBar(content: Text('Check your inbox')));
      // }
      log('Go to the next page');
      // } on AuthException catch (error) {
      //   ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      //       content: const Text('Error occured, please retry.'),
      //       backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error));
    } catch (e) {
      log('error happened while registering user $e');
      yield ErrorState(message: e.toString());
    }
  } else {
    yield ShowErrorState();
  }
  } else if (event is LoginTappedEvent) {
    yield NextLoginPageState();
  }
}
```

}

I tried looking at these previous questions and it doesn't seem like we should access build context within a bloc

https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/1030

[Is it ok to pass BuildContext to BLoC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58505388/is-it-ok-to-pass-buildcontext-to-bloc)

Comment: so what's the problem?